# Xamarin Forms Animation MVVM way

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, code-behind

I want to make an animation that gets fired when a `frame` is clicked. I already have a command that's bound on the `GestureRecognizers` but that's part of my `ViewModel` and putting view code inside the ViewModel breaks the mvvm. Do you know where the animation code should be placed?(i want to perform the animation and after that to execute the command from the ViewModel)

Answer (score 1):

You can run the animation in the code-behind and at the end call your `ViewModel` method (the action currently executed by the bound command), no need for the Command in this case, only the event.

**xaml**

```
<Image Source="tapped.jpg">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"/>
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

**Code-behind**

```
async void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
     //await the animation
     (BindingContext as YourViewModel).CommandAction();
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
void CommandAction()
{
...
}
```

Comment: That's right but I'm using a `frame` and the docs says that `tapped` is obsolete and the `command` should be used instead.

Comment: Could you send the link where it says Tapped is obsolete i couldn't find it ?

Comment: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.tapgesturerecognizer.-ctor?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_TapGestureRecognizer__ctor_System_Action_Xamarin_Forms_View__` sorry if I'm wrong

Comment: I was not aware about that, I am still using it when needed with no issue, but if you don't want to use it because it's obsolete then you need to use Command and since you want to follow mvvm pattern it should be in vm...we're back at the starting point.

Comment: I will use `tapped` until i'll find something else, but I'm still waiting for another ideas ^_^. Thank you for your help.

Comment: no worries, you're welcome happy to help :)